# How to solve "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" in create_message() function?

Tags: python, email, encoding, google-api, gmail-api

I'm getting an error in creating a new message using create_message(). function listed over https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts.

```
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

> Error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: are you running python3 ? also at which exact place are you getting this , you will need to add 'b' according

Answer (score 0):

[base64.urlsafe_b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode) expects `bytes`, but the type of `message.as_string()` is `str`.

Use the message's [as_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.as_bytes) method instead.

```
return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())}
```